# What drove Tyrell Wellick to do this deed and why did he regret it afterwards?

Tags: plot-explanation, mr-robot

Tyrell Wellick from *Mr. Robot* is a careful, ambitious and manipulative character. It is obvious why he seduced Sharon on two occasions, first being when Sharon sat on toilet seat, second being kissing and eventually killing Sharon on the E Corp roof. Tyrell wanted to use Sharon to get back to Sharon's husband, who took Tyrell's dream job as E Corp's CTO.

But why Tyrell kill her?

- Did he do that on purpose? If so, why did he panic and flee the scene while leaving so many evidences behind, e.g. fabric from his suits, his hair and possibly video footage. Let alone, Tyrell's wife does not know about this murder until two detectives show up at front door.

My taking on this is:

- Tyrell wants to get to Sharon's husband by seducing Sharon, but Tyrell has some kind of fetish that drives him violent and angry during sexual encounters, it can be witnessed when Tyrell's bedroom has SM sex toys ready, and his wife seems to be fond of it too. Tyrell kills Sharon when he is out of control accidentally.

What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 11):

Tyrell is constantly being ridiculed by his wife but, being the weak one in their relationship, he has to take it.

When he realizes that he can actually hurt Sharon after she's been ridiculing him too, he can't stop himself.

Btw, he was goaded by his wife into confronting Sharon again, so it's also a way of asserting himself in his couple.

Comment: Yes, definitely agree you on this one. +1

Comment: That couple's relationship is so messed up...